# How connect Context with Redirect

Tags: reactjs

I want to send information to second page if the user is logged in . I would like use Context to that.
Something about my code :

```
const Login = () => {
...
const [logged, setLogged] = React.useState(0);
... 
const log = () => {
    if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
      setLogged(1);
    }

...
  return (
  {logged == 1 && (
          <Redirect to="/page" />
      )}
```

I want to send `logged` to `/page` but i don't know how . None guide help me .`Page` is actually empty React file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways handle that:

1. Passing `state` to route(as described in [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object)):

```
  {logged == 1 && (
          <Redirect to={{ path: "/page", state: { isLoggedIn: true } }} />
      )}
```

And your component under `/page` route will access that flag as `this.props.location.state.isLoggedIn`

2. Utilize some global app state(Redux, Context API with `<Provider>` at root level or anything alike).

To me second option is better for keeping auth information:

1. Probably not only one target component will want to check if user is authorized
2. I'd expect you will need to store some authorization data to send with new requests(like JWT token) so just boolean flah accessible in single component would not be enough.
3. some operation on auth information like say `logout()` or `refreshToken()` will be probably needed in different components not in single one.

But finally it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **skyboyer**
I solved this problem with Context method .I will try tell you how i do this becouse maybe someone will have the same problem
I created new file

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
const LoginInfo = React.createContext();

export const LoginInfoProvider = props => {
  const [infoLog, setInfoLog] = React.useState("");
  const login = name => {
    setInfoLog(name);
  };
  const logout = () => {
    setInfoLog("old");
  };
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <LoginInfo.Provider
      value={{
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        infolog: infoLog
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </LoginInfo.Provider>
  );
};
export const LoginInfoConsumer = LoginInfo.Consumer;
```

In `App.js` add `LoginInfoProvider`

```
<Router>
 <LoginInfoProvider>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
  <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
 </LoginInfoProvider>
</Router>
```

In page with login (parts of code in my question) i added `LoginInfoConsumer`

```
<LoginInfoConsumer>
```